# Class constructor list remains empty throughout Python code

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a stack, then use a module called reverse_list to add something to the stack using a prebuild push module within the stack class, and then pop it out of the stack in to a list, then add it back to the stack and return it. 
But when i run the function it looks like the items do not get properly added to the property self.items, as the debugger shows that it forever remains at "[]", which is not a desired result, which also means it skips the other functions that require the list to be anything but empty.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        if type(item) == list or type(item) == tuple:
            for items in item:
                self.items.append(items)
        else:
            self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        self.items.pop()

    def reverse_list(self, arr):

        classer = Stack()
        classer.push(my_list)
        temp_list = []
        while self.items:
            temp_list.append(self.items.pop())
        for elements in temp_list:
            self.items.append(elements)
        return self.items


if __name__ == "__main__":
    starter = Stack()
    print(starter.reverse_list(my_list))
```

Current output: []

Desired output: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Danke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `reverse_list` you make another instance of `Stack` and you push your list onto that. But that other instance is not `self`, so `self.items` is still empty.

I think you want to get rid of `classer` and just use `self`.